# session_encode failed how to find out which part is tripping it up?

Tags: php, session

After my server has been upgraded to PHP 5.6 one of my modules has stopped to work.

The module is a who's online module that shows current users shopping carts.

there error I am getting is:

```
Warning: session_decode(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed
```

Here is the Var_dump:

```
string(160) "cart|O:12:"shoppingCart":4:{s:8:"contents";a:0:{}s:5:"total";i:0;s:6:"weight";i:0;s:12:"content_type";b:0;}language|s:7:"english";languages_id|s:1:"1";currency|"
```

Here is the code that creates the string:

```
$session_data_cart = substr($session_data, $start_cart, $i);
$session_data_currency = substr($session_data, $start_currency, (strpos($session_data, ';', $start_currency) - $start_currency + 1));

session_decode($session_data_cart);
session_decode($session_data_currency);
```

So my question is what is all of the sudden tripping up the session_decode?

Nothing has changed but maybe the way session_decode has from the previous php version? I'm just not sure what I am looking for and the PHP manual doesnt provide much insight I don't think on this.